# Android Image sending intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to share an image from the drawables in my application.  i keep getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException:/abc.jpg (read-only file system)`

my code is

```
  private String SaveCache(int resID) {
            String path = "";  
            try {
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resID);
                File cacheDir = this.getExternalCacheDir();
                File downloadingMediaFile = new File(cacheDir, "abc.jpg");
                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
                while (true) {
                    int rd = is.read(buf, 0, 256);
                    if (rd == -1 || rd == 0)
                        break;
                    out.write(buf, 0, rd);              
                }
                is.close();
                out.close();
                return downloadingMediaFile.getPath();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return path;
        }



        private void ImageShare() {
            String path = SaveCache(R.drawable.testsend);
            Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + path));       
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Choose share method."));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Any help is appreciated, if more info is required i will be happy to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the external storage is mounted.

From the docs of [getExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29):

> Returns the path of the directory holding application cache files on
>   external storage. Returns null if external storage is not currently
>   mounted so it could not ensure the path exists; you will need to call
>   this method again when it is available.

Comment: don't you just hate it when you spend an hour mashing the keyboard to figure out the silly little mistake.in the process of checking the external storage,i figured out that i forgot to add the permission for external storage.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.anddev.org/post3469.html#p3469

You need to use

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(name, MODE);

as mentioned in the example.